# Mail issue pimcore symfony on AmlaLinux server

Tags: php, symfony, email, pimcore

Facing an issue with mail. When we are trying to send mail, it is giving following error

**Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException: Unable to write bytes on the wire. in /vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/Stream/AbstractStream.php:46**

At first it looks like a permission error. So tried with 777 + apache owner permission. But no result.

When we checked port 25 and it working fine

`telnet ip-address 25`

Trying IP-address...
Connected to ip-address.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 scl-ex102.ad.ssc-scl.ch Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sat, 26 Nov 2022 17:23:32 +0100

System OS AlmaLinux9
Pimcore version 10.2
php 8.1

Do we need to install anything else like sendmail or something else or any configuration changes in php.ini or do we need to install any php module to send mail.

I tried one more option like simple php mail function. On browser it is fail without any fatal error. but when I tried it on command line it returned an error like

`php mail.php`

sh: line 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: No such file or directory

Please suggest solution to work mail functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands fixed the issue.

```
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)

sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var public/var

sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var public/var
```